# Adding ssl certificates for the cCURL in android has errors

Tags: android, c++, curl, android-ndk, openssl

I have cross built the curl and openssl for the android with help of this link [Using cURL in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952169/using-curl-in-android) .. 
I am able to build succesfully . and now I am trying to run my application , in my application I need to add my own certificates , when I tried to add the **certificates which are stored in sdcard via my native code** ,I am  getting the following error response from the curl i.e CURLE_SSL_CERTPROBLEM (58)=>problem with the local client certificate. and if remove all certificates in my below application and if I use the simple https curl client with out certificates  get the following error CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE (77) .

Here with I have put my code , and in that I am just trying to read the certificates from sdcard(I had copied and pasted in the sdcard) .

am I loading the certificates properly ?

//Inteface funciton that will recieve web page fom Java

```
  {
  pageInfo_t page;
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
   char *buffer;

 static const char *pCertFile = "/mnt//sdcard/sslcerts/33330001-root.x509";
 static const char *pCACertFile="/mnt//sdcard/sslcerts/root.x509.crt";
 pKeyName  = "/mnt/sdcard/sslcerts/33330001-root-privkey.der"; 

 const char *pKeyName;
 const char *pKeyType;

const char *pEngine;
const jbyte *webpage;

pKeyType  = "DER";
pEngine   = NULL;

webpage = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, webpageJStr, NULL);
if (webpage == NULL) {
  return NULL; /* OutOfMemoryError already thrown */
}

page.data = (char *)malloc(16 * 1024);
page.len = 0;
if (page.data)
 memset(page.data, 32, 16 * 1024);

buffer = (char *)malloc(1024);

 curl = curl_easy_init();
 if(curl) {
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, webpage);
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, HTTPData);
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &page);
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE,"DER");

  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLCERT,pCertFile);

  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE,pKeyType);

  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLKEY,pKeyName);

  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_CAINFO,pCACertFile);

 curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1L);
 res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* always cleanup */
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, webpageJStr, webpage);
if(res == 0) {
  if (buffer) {
    page.data[page.len < 256 ? page.len : 256] = '\0';
sprintf(buffer, "pagedata(%d): %s. done.\n", page.len, page.data);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buffer);
  }
}
sprintf(buffer, "Result %d", res);
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buffer);
} else {
  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Unable to init cURL");
}
}
```

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this line

```
#define CURL_CA_BUNDLE "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

to `curl_config.h` while building libCurl.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for suggestion .. I guess it will load the default CA bundle . In my case I have to pass my own certificates with  ECC_CCM chiper suite .. Still I did not get how to load my own certificates at the android ndk-level .