# simple C++ async http client

Tags: android, c++, ios, http, asynchronous

I need a HTTP client in C + + that runs on mobile platforms such as Android and iOS, do not know any that have this purpose, could indicate me some?

if there is one that is asynchronous still more help.

in android I have a https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http is very good, ans in IOS I have https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking this is very good too, but they're in Java and Obj-c and I need one in C++ for use in both simultaneously.

Comment: @Default actually Android supports Java and C++ and iOS accepts Obj-C and C++. In C++ you can plan for both. I'm doing it, the only problem with using C++ in this case is that you can not manipulate the GUI but to solve it I use java for android on your GUI, in IOS Obj-c in your GUI and in business rule and use the same code for both, using C++, it's the reason i want a C++ async http library. No in C++ and i not wanna use C# and Mono, I prefer use a native platform language.

Answer (score 2):

Folks have been using cURL (client) and libcurl (library for client) on Android. There's plenty of activity on it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6484459/1794538) for a project to building it under NDK. Use [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl+android) to look for questions tagged both 'android' and 'curl'. There's parallel effort to use libcurl on iOS.