# Android NDK refer to external libraries in JNI

Tags: android, c++, curl, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have written C++ file in **JNI** folder of my application. I am using **Windows** system with **NDK** and **Cygwin 1.7**.
I want reffer to CURL library available in Cygwin.
How can we refer to external .h(libraries/header) files while creating JNI application in Android?
I have created a combined Android and C++ project. But I am referring CURL header file. When I build the project I am getting **fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory** issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please used this [tutorial](http://psrdotcom.blogspot.fr/2011/12/android-ndk-jni-windows-xp7-with-3264.html) is nice one.

Don't forgot to change this setting after convert project to C / C ++ native project.

Builder Settings to Build Command

```
bash C:\tools\android-ndk-r8b-windows\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-build
```

This is my path of NDK you can change this path accordingly your NDK path.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have already created a combined Android and C++ project. The tutorial you are suggesting helps creating simple JNI application. But I am referring CURL header file. When I build the project I am getting **fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory** issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

Converting from Android project to C/C++ project:
Right click on your project name, go to 'Android Tools' and click 'Add native support'

Adding paths to external .h files:
Right click on your project name, go to 'Properties', under 'C/C++ General', go to 'Paths and Symbols', under 'Includes' tab, add the folder in which your .h file is. Remember to add to all languages and configurations if asked.

Also, since you are in Windows, I think you will need to change your Build command (which is in the 'C/C++ Build' section in project properties) to "bash C:\Development\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd"

Comment: I have updated my question. What does **Add native support** feature does?

Comment: add native support creates a combined android and c++ project. since you have already done that, skip that step.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$/PATH/TO/YOUR/curl.h
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$/PATH/TO/YOUR/libcurl.a.for.android -lcurl
```

The `libcurl.a` you have installed in cygwin is not usable for android, you need a version targetting android. If you don't have it, build it yourself.

Comment: There is no curl.so file in Cygwin. ??? I actually created a simple http request project in C++ for test and I linked libcurl.a file at that time.

Comment: @256 You are right, you need a `libcurl.a` for static linking, not the .so

Answer (score 0):

When you get that libcurl.a file, do not forget to copy the headers folder of curl (get into your **usr/include/curl** from Cygwin) and add this folder to the JNI one in your project, so it knows the headers while compiling.

Which means also referring in your **Android.mk** :

for the libcurl library

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libcurl.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/curl
```

and for your C++ files

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/curl
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcurl
```