# Fetch Data from website using curl in Android?

Tags: android

I have simple application in which i have to fetch data from website. I know how to fetch data from URL using HTTP post method but i have to implement it using CURL. I mean first we fetch the data from website using curl and then i have to insert this data into database. My website link is

http://pharmaciesdetanger.ma/index.php?option=com_gmapfp&view=gmapfp&layout=categorie&catid=24&id_perso=0&Itemid=23

I have searched over the internet but didn't find any solution. How to do it?
Please Help me to achieve this in Android.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.in/2010/05/porting-of-libcurl-to-android-os-using.html

reference

[Using cURL in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952169/using-curl-in-android)